# Unusual IPv6 address from recvfrom, starting with a00

Tags: c, ipv6

recvfrom on IPv6 sockets (GNU/Linux) gives unusual addresses for the client/from address of the form `a00::<two_radom_bytes>:</64_network_prefix>`.

What are theses addresses called or by what search terms can more information be found?

Comment: thanks, I removed the claim from the question.

Comment: No such addresses have ever been assigned. So this is something specific to your environment, which you haven't described. I don't think there's any way anybody can help you with this, as it stands, without a _LOT_ more information.

Comment: Perhaps you are hitting an endianess issue. Seeing the code you use to look at the ip6 address would be helpful though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the problem staring right at me; I used `&addr` instead of `&addr.sin6_addr` for function inet_ntop.
Sorry for bugging everyone with this silly problem.

Comment: Maybe you were better off with `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`. At least, I found that easier...

Comment: Also this should have made the compiler throwing at least one warning at you during compilation. If it did not `-Wall` makes GCC quite sensitive, `-pedantic` and `-Wextra` even more.